# How to assign workers?

Tags: fallout-4

I don't understand assigning workers in this game. I have a bunch of crops that need tending, but not many of them are getting the attention needed.  I have tried to assign one person to do it. Do I have to click assign on each individual plant? Or do I just click 'Command' and then look at the items I want to assign?

Answer (score 1):

Each worker can tend up to 9 plants. You must select each crop individually.

Comment: One more probably dumb question...When I highlight a plant or guard post and it shows a red vault boy, does that mean it doesn't have an assigned person to it? I assigned someone to the post and it was green for a bit, then went back to red.  Please advise and thanks i advance.

Comment: @user129446 I'm actually not sure, I haven't played around much with the defense mechanics. Hopefully someone else sees your comment. If not, ask another question so it'll get more visibility.